# Trying to make a for loop with random numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop, random

I'm trying to make a for loop that gives a random seat number to each name the user enters. So the user tells me the names, and how many seats there are and I need to make a for loop that randomly assigns each name a random seat?  Here's what I'm doing, but I'm not sure how I can make this right:

```
for(seats=1; seats<=kids.size(); seats++)
{
    int result=(int)(Math.random()* (kids.size()) );
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

It just returns 0 for however many names there are. I'm pretty sure I've messed up a lot on this but any help is appreciated :)

Comment: remember that after you assign a seat to someone, that seat can no longer be assigned. So you can't just trust Math.random() * kids.size() to do the right thing unless you a) remove a kid once it's assigned and b) remove the seat from the seat pool. On that note: where's your seat pool?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` returns double values between `0.0` and `1.0`, so even when you are multiplying it with `kids.size()`, if size is <<1000 , there is a great possibility that the multiplication result is still `less than 1` and so `converting to int would return 0`.

as an example, a workaround to create random numbers between 0 and 99 would be:

```
(math.random()*10000)%100
```

Also, as for your second requirement, you can have a `bit array of length equal to the maximum seat number`, then you can generate `random numbers less than this max seat number`, and whichever seat gets allocated, `set the bit in the array to 1`, next time before assignment, check `if bit is already 1, then generate again`, else assign this seat.

Comment: but not every time. Math.random is reasonably uniform, and random * size will statistically not be 0 most of the time, but some value between 0 and size.

Comment: Math.random() actually returns doubles between 0.0 and 1.0 (not 0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Try the class `Random` (part of the java std library). It lets you generate random integers with given bounds.

```
Random myGenerator = new Random();
for(seats = 1; seats <= kids.size(); seats++) {
    int result = myGenerator.nextInt(kids.size());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

But bear in mind you'd need extra code to make sure the seat numbers generated are distinct.

```
Random myGenerator = new Random();

// keep track of the seats that are already taken
List<Integer> takenSeats = new ArrayList<Integer>(kids.size());

for(seats = 1; seats <= kids.size(); seats++) {
    int result = myGenerator.nextInt(kids.size());

    // keep trying until we get a distinct seat
    while(takenSeats.contains(result)) {
        result = myGenerator.nextInt(kids.size());
    }

    // now record that this seat is taken
    takenSeats.add(result);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a double, and you're casting to an integer, which floors the result. Therefore, is your size greater than 1? If thats the problem, simply increment your expression before casting to an integer: `(int) (Math.random()* kids.size() + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*kids.size())+1)
```

The only problem is that this wouldn't assure that your numbers are distinct. If this is of concern, please state your question as so.

For the record, there are various algorithms you could use. One would be to have a sort of seat list as an array-list. Then when someone gets a seat, remove it from the list of available seats.

Every time you go through your for-loop, you should check the results of your Math.random to see if that result is in the list of available seats. If not, run the Math.random again.

The while() loop that @peter has would do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the `Random` class to generate your numbers, because it allows you to generate them within a certain range.

Secondly, I would recommend using a `Map` (the most common concrete implementation of which is the `HashMap`) to associate your random numbers with your seat IDs. This way you can make sure that all the random numbers you use are unique.

Assuming that `kids` is an `ArrayList<String>`, you could do:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Random generator = new Random();
for (String kid : kids) {
    int number = r.nextInt(kids.size());

    // if the number has been used already, generate a new one
    while (map.containsValue(number))
        number = r.nextInt(kids.size());

    // associate the kid (key) and number (value) in the HashMap
    map.put(kid, number);
}
```

Use of an ehnance `for-loop` is just syntactic sugar, but in this instance it will improve your code's readability.

More information: [Random Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), [HashMap Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)